# Ubuntu 20.04 with ZFS, using a mainline kernel version results in "Failed to load ZFS modules"

Tags: boot, kernel, initramfs, zfs

If I boot with a kernel only a single minor version above (or below) the three shipped with my ubuntu 20.04 I get :

```
[         0.691104] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

Failed to load ZFS modules.
Manually load the modules and exit.


Busybox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.1) built-in shell
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)_
```

If I select my normal kernel version : 5.4.0.40.44 then it boots normally.

I followed the "at install time" choice of [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/1245550/573671)
and I'm still getting this error.

Why did his fix not work for me?

UPDATE:

I added "splash" to my grub arguments, which I had previously removed, in order to fix login loop.

and I got this instead :

```
[         0.660812] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
[         0.864542] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000...
[         0.864561] MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
[         0.868251] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000...

Busybox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.1) built-in shell
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)_
```

Which is a different error but I guess it stems from the same thing.

UPDATE 2 :

and with `nomodeset` it's the second version of the error also.

Comment: please provide the kernel versions that do not work, you only provided the version that works, `5.4.0.40.44`.

Comment: I did actually say which doesn't work: any other. (5.4.3, for example)

Comment: From where? Is it an Ubuntu kernel or a mainline kernel? I am not aware of any Ubuntu kernel with that type of version numbering.And no, mainline knows nothing about zfs.

Comment: so it's because of mainline? I basically have to wait until an officially released new ubuntu kernel to have zfs support + new kernel?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: ok thanks that is non-obvious, since it's now just an option to tick an since ubuntu now ships with ZFS mainline could totally build the kernels they offer with ZFS i don't understand why not. is building my own with ZFS advisable?

Comment: This happened with me today `5.15.5-76051505-generic` is the kernel that was installed during an apt update and I get an `(initramfs)` prompt.  I too have to manually select an old kernel which is `5.13.0-7620-generic` 

It mentions to manually load zfs.  Which `modpropbe zfs` doesn't show any issues. Which I ran and then exited.  I got a bunch of errors. 

Too bad this bug still happens when upgrading a 1 yr 1/2 later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, kernels from [the Ubuntu mainline PPA](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D) use the master source code from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/). There is no such thing as zfs in the master code, and its inclusion at the master level has been [controversial and has licensing concerns](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2020/01/linus-torvalds-zfs-statements-arent-right-heres-the-straight-dope/).

It would defeat the purpose of the mainline kernels if they were to include any downstream (distribution) modifications.

Yes, you could compile your own kernels starting from the Ubuntu source code. However, you might achieve what you want by using one of the [current Ubuntu unstable kernels](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/unstable) for the current development version, 20.10., keeping in mind that development level issues are not supported on this forum.

Comment: thank you very much. I understand that I would be outside the scope of support I just want to try something, if it doesn't work i'll just go back to my current kernel. I added the PPA but don't understand how to use these unstable kernels, they didn't show up in the mainline app (which I subsequently uninstalled) if there's a ppa that means I can download and install these kernels entirely in the terminal right? Also I can use them without having to switch to 20.10, right?

Comment: The kernels should work fine on 20.04. Just drill down into the  link and decide what you want to try. get the .deb files and install them yourself with dpkg. For example from [here](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/bootstrap/+build/19464688)

Comment: that looks good to me thanks!